# Memory leak in av_interleaved_write_frame

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

In my video recording application for OSX, i am using ffmpeg library.
I found few memory leaks in the application. 
In the process of resolving it, i discovered that there is some leak in

int av_interleaved_write_frame(AVFormatContext *s, AVPacket *pkt)

Has anyone faced any such issue? Can you please help me to resolve this memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using a very common library like ffmpeg, and you are facing a memory leak, most of the time the leak is not in the library you use, but somewhere in the code you wrote.

That is the first step to solve your memory leak problem.

If you are absolutly sure that the problem come from FFMPEG, so have a look to the [open issues of the project](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/report)

And then if the issue is not opened you can submit the bug to the development team...
But before to do it check several time that the bug isn't on your side, and again, in a very common library like FFMPEG, I don't think that the bug is in the function  av_interleaved_write_frame.

Why do you think that the bug is in this function ?